# Circuitikz question on how to Let the voltage label go to the left？

Tags: circuitikz

MWE is down here.

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \begin{document}
   \begin{circuitikz}[european]
   \ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}
   \draw (0,0) to[vsource=$u_\mathrm{S}$] (0,-3);
   \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I got the wrong result when I used 'vsource,l_='

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{circuitikz}[european]
   \ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}
   \draw (0,0) to[vsource,l_=$u_\mathrm{S}$] (0,-3);
   \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]
You can see the '+' and the '-' is missing.
How to get the results right in European style and this ctikzset?

Comment: Actually without the `ctikzset` the issue is also visible, there the downwards arrow disappears when using `l_=`. Furthermore, the issue also occurs (with or without this `ctikzset`) with `vsource, l=`, which is supposed to be equivalent to `vsource=`.

Comment: Yes, because `l=` means "label", and `v=` means "voltage". Voltage generators automatically pass their argument to `v=`, current generators to `i=`, and all the other ones to `l=`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Qite simple, just replace `vsource=$u_\mathrm{S}$` with `vsource, v_=$u_\mathrm{S}$`:

```
 \documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 
 \begin{document}
   \begin{circuitikz}[european]
   \ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}
   \draw (0,0) to[vsource, v_=$u_\mathrm{S}$] (0,-3);
   \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. I can't believe I didn't see this command in the Circuitikz manual.

Comment: @EVISTIX, you are welcome. Documentation of package is due to permanently evolution of package became huge ...

Answer (score 3):

Referring to Section 3.1.2 of [`circuitikzmanual.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), we can use the predefined border anchors to draw the notations manually.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
\ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}
\draw (0,0) to (0,-3);
\node [vsourceshape, rotate=90, name=vs] at (0,-1.5) {};
\node at (vs.45) {$+$};
\node at (vs.135) {$-$};
\node[left] at (vs.90) {$u_{S}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```